# Resharper unable to find javascript files for Jasmine

Tags: visual-studio, jasmine, resharper

I'm trying to run my Jasmine tests using resharper.  Using a simple HTML test runner page works.  Using the resharper test runner fails to find the javascript files (listed with reference).  The HTML page and the javascript specs are in the same folder.  What am I missing?

This Works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/underscore.min.js"></script>

    <!-- angular app files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../web/estore/scripts/common/underscoreApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../web/estore/scripts/common/directives/dccdirectivesapp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../web/estore/scripts/common/directives/dccdirectivesapp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../web/estore/scripts/common/directives/cart/dcccartcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../web/estore/scripts/common/directives/cart/dcccartservice.js"></script>

    <!-- test files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../AngularJS/dccCartControllerSpecs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This does not find the JavaScript files referenced:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="/../Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js" />  // trying different ways to reference the files
/// <reference path="/../Scripts/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js" />
/// <reference path="/../Scripts/angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="/../Scripts/angular-mocks.min.js" />
/// <reference path="/../Scripts/underscore.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular-mocks.js"/>

/// <reference path="/../../web/estore/scripts/common/underscoreApp.js" />
/// <reference path="/../../web/estore/scripts/common/directives/dccdirectivesapp.js" />
/// <reference path="/../../web/estore/scripts/common/directives/cart/dcccartcontroller.js" />
/// <reference path="/../../web/estore/scripts/common/directives/cart/dcccartservice.js" />

describe("Given a dcc module", function() {
... etc
```

Further, to troubleshoot, I added a test.js to the same folder as my specs and SpecRunner.html.  See how when this shows up in the browser it is empty?  The reference path is as simple as:

```
 /// <reference path="test.js"/>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]